# How to find all rows that match every value given in filter criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `user` and `user_role` tables.

The `user_role` table has two columns:

```
user_id
role_name
```

I want to find users that have multiple roles at the same time, for example '*admin*' and '*moderator*'.

How can I build this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two joins, one for filtering admins, and the other one for moderators:

```
SELECT user.*
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_role admins
ON admins.user_id = user.id
AND admins.role_name = 'admin'
INNER JOIN user_role mods
ON mods.user_id = user.id
AND mods.role_name = 'moderator'
```

Answer (score 3):

Following query uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join the tables `user` and `user_role` to find all users who belong to admin and moderator. Then it filters only users who belong to both admin and moderator roles by finding a *DISTINCT* count on the `role_name`. If you add another role, then the value 2 used in the HAVING clause should be changed accordingly.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a07/1)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    user_id     INT         NOT NULL
  , user_name   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_role
(
    user_id     INT         NOT NULL
  , role_name   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name) VALUES
    (1, 'user 1'),
    (2, 'user 2'),
    (3, 'user 3'),
    (4, 'user 4'),
    (5, 'user 5'),
    (6, 'user 6');

INSERT INTO user_role (user_id, role_name) VALUES
    (1, 'admin'),
    (1, 'moderator'),
    (3, 'moderator'),
    (2, 'admin'),
    (5, 'admin'),
    (2, 'moderator'),
    (5, 'admin'),
    (4, 'moderator'),
    (4, 'moderator');

SELECT          u.user_id
            ,   u.user_name
FROM            user        u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_role   ur
ON              ur.user_id  = u.user_id
WHERE           ur.role_name IN ('admin', 'moderator')
GROUP BY        u.user_id
HAVING          COUNT(DISTINCT ur.role_name) = 2;
```

*Output*:

```
USER_ID USER_NAME 
------- ---------
   1    user 1
   2    user 2
```